# Hefeweissen ingredients question

Tags: beer, all-grain, small-batch

it's my first post in here. I've just done my first batch of weissbier (or any other). It turned out quite alright so I'd like to repeat it to check I wasn't lucky. 
However, since it was from a kit I'd like to buy the ingredients in bulk from elsewhere rather than buying their £10 ingredients-only kit. 
The following link is the ingredients kit:

[brewcraftbeer](http://www.brewcraftbeer.co.uk/wheat-dreams-bavarian-hefeweizen-25-p.asp)

I was looking for some help on the (some) type of crushed grain I can try to buy, for instance, from here:

[maltmiller](http://www.themaltmiller.co.uk/index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=17)

in order to brew another weissbier. Perhaps it's not as straightforward as I think though...

Comment: Those are the same link; the "maltmiller" link is not correct.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically as straightforward as you think.

Weissbier/weizen recipes vary, but you're looking at 40-60% wheat malt, with the balance being mostly pilsner or pale/2-row malt, maybe a touch of carapils for residual sugars/body.

The biggest thing to note is that crushed grain as a much more limited lifetime than whole grain that you crush on demand. But properly stored (vacuum sealed bags in the freezer) you can probably keep it around for a couple-few months.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few recipes that you can look at for help: http://beersmithrecipes.com/searchrecipe?uid=&term=Weizen&submit.x=13&submit.y=9&sort=Best+Match&allgrain=1&rated=4

Answer (score 0):

Under German purity law any beer labeled Weiss or Weizen must be at least 50% malted wheat in its grain bill. That it purely trivial for a homebrewer, do what your palate likes.

Along with jsled, there's nothing like milling your grain on brewday to add to the experience, but a mill does have a pretty big initial investment. ($200 us)

Try to find a Local Home Brew Supply store to get your grain. They usually have a mill on hand for customer use. It's recommended to use milled grain fresh. I've seen varied opinions on how long it will keep but 2 weeks is a general max for properly stored milled grain. Most kits are milled close to shipping date, but you really never know unless you mill it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It does make sense. In way seems equivalent to roasted coffee. It looses freshness quite fast after grinding - the reason why I grind my own. Will definitely consider the option of a mill for the grain.